# Wordpress overwrite contact form mail_2 body

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

Currently I am facing a problem to overwrite the body content of `the mail_2` in the hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail`.

I am trying to rewrite a wpcf7 shortcode to a more proper presentation of the content with some html modifications.

The problem is that I can't overwrite the mail body. After I rewrite the body and print directly the result it seems to be back as the default body. When I print my modification directly, I see the modifications as I want them to be.

Example of code:

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "cf7_wpcf7_custom", 99, 1);

# Before sending email
function cf7_wpcf7_custom($properties, $contact_form_obj) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $wpcf7      = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    $wpcf7->mail_2['body'] = str_replace('[checkbox-1]', '..test..', $wpcf7->mail_2['body']);

    // No changes appearing
    var_dump($wpcf7->mail_2['body']);

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook is performed before the additional mail is set. So it will be overwritten.

We can modify the mail body by using the filter `wpcf7_additional_mail`.

For example:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_additional_mail', 'customize_mail_2', 10, 2);
function customize_mail_2($additional_mail, $contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $wpcf7      = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    $additional_mail['mail_2']['body'] = '..do your replacement stuff';
    return $additional_mail;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change Email 1 and 2 with following code in functions.php and add some self inserted code:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_couponnr_to_mail_body' );

function wpcf7_add_couponnr_to_mail_body($contact_form){

  // get mail property
  $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // returns array with mail values
  $mail2 = $contact_form->prop( 'mail_2' ); // returns array with mail values

  $couponnr = ...some insert code...;

  // add date (or other content) to email body
  $mail['body'] = str_replace("%%%COUPONNR%%%", $couponnr, $mail['body']);
  $mail2['body'] = str_replace("%%%COUPONNR%%%", $couponnr, $mail2['body']);

  // set mail property with changed value(s)
  $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );
  $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail_2' => $mail2 ) );

}
```